# iisexpress.exe is under program files but visual studio 2017 says cant find it in programfiles(x86)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have visual studio 2012 and visual studio 2017 in one x64 PC.
I can see that i have two iisexpress folders one under program files(x86) and another under program files
the iisexpress folder under program files(x86) has no iisexpress.exe file
but iisexpress folder under program files has iisexpress.exe file
when running a dotnet core MVC project in visual studio. it complains there is no iisexpress.exe under program files(x86)

Comment: now i select the "use the 64bit version of iis express" and it seems that problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can comment is that your IIS Express installation is broken. `iisexpress.exe` must present in both folders, so that you can run both 32 bit and 64 bit of the process.

You found a workaround, but the ultimate solution is probably reinstalling IIS 10 Express.

Comment: "IIS Express 10 32 bit could not be installed in a 64 bit windows" LOL, there is quite a lot of 32 bit applications on a 64 bit Windows. What happens if you try to reinstall IIS 10 Express again? Any error message?

Comment: Yes i have many 32bit apps under program files(x86) and all of them are 32bit apps. Yesterday i downloaded iis express 32 bit and tried to install it but installer says it can be installed in a 64bit windows

Comment: The `amd64` MSI packages would install both 32 and 64 bit. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264 Well, there is still quite a lot you need to learn.

Comment: Yes you were right. iisexpress.exe was moved to chest by antivirus.